# Azure C# Deployment Scripts become inaccessible

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I recently built & deployed my first C# MVC website on Azure, but I am finding that the [scripts folder](http://lipstate.com/scripts/?v=8-nQ5fLPOWbFbJ3aNGN9S-Cax5jWLtBVGkIQKVKaKMc1) is not accessible. The [CSS path](http://lipstate.com/styles?v=uN9B1hvN-FmZu5InjOI3atLl7v20twIOG8AC6McXPYw1) is OK. How do I set the permissions of the scripts folder in azure?

in a localhost version of the site, scripts are served as:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/frontend.js"></script>
```

in the azure version, it is all turned into:

```
<script src="/scripts?v=8-nQ5fLPOWbFbJ3aNGN9S-Cax5jWLtBVGkIQKVKaKMc1"></script>
```

to clarify on the original question, i can access the individual javascript files, if i [address directly](http://lipstate.com/scripts/frontend.js) to them. its just the azure-ified script tag that i can not access.

Comment: can you access it via Microsoft Webmatrix tool or via cloud explorer extension in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you find the scripts folder and script files using FTP or Kudu?

[image]

If you can't find them, it means that the scripts haven't been published to Azure Web App. Please make sure you have set the Build Action property as "Content" of these script files before you publish your web application.

[image]

If these files are exist in Azure Web App and you can't access it with a URL, please make sure the URL which used to address the script file is right. For example, if the scripts folder is under wwwroot folder. To access the files under scripts folder, the URL should be

```
http://yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net/scripts/scriptfile.js
```

> <script src="/scripts?v=8-nQ5fLPOWbFbJ3aNGN9S-Cax5jWLtBVGkIQKVKaKMc1">

You are using script bundle in your project. Please check your project, there is a BundleConfig file under App_Start folder.

The URL of script will change to upper format if you publish your project to web server or change the debug property to false in web.config.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
```

To solve your issue, please make sure Microsoft.Web.Optimization DLL is installed on your web project and add following configuration under <system.webServer>  <modules> tag in web.config.

```
<add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
```

If you want to disable the script bundle, you could set EnableOptimizations property to false in Application_Start method of Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
}
```

Comment: I am able to access a js file from the web address without issue. All items seem to say content for the build action. Its just the garbled script item that i can't access. i think that only happened when i switched from local IIS express to actually publishing on azure

Comment: It seems that the JS files are broken during the upload progress. Please try to delete these broken files and upload them again.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure that that is true, i can access the individual files on the published site, its just the process of it getting turned into the single link that something goes wrong. Do you know what that is called? im sure i just dont know the correct question to ask. I have updated the question showing the change in the served script tags.

Comment: Updated my reply based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you, the bundler is definitely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to set **app.UseStaticFiles()** in your Startup.cs

Comment: Hi Everton, my application is MVC 5, which doesn't have a startup.cs, in googling the method list above it seems to be in relation to asp.net core. if it does apply to an mvc5 application, can you further clarify? i can't find this method in any sub-context of the global.asax application_start method that would use the proposed .UseStaticFiles()